# Gunicorn logging differs from flask logging

Tags: flask, gunicorn

`flask` and `gunicorn` are not generating the same log messages. Many `INFO` log messages generated when using `flask` are not generated by `gunicorn`. Why, and how is this fixed?
These two examples handle the same URL:

`flask`:

```
(.venv) [sc_repos/msdw_web_api]$ flask --app web_apis run --debug
[2023-05-22 13:03:10,173] INFO in __init__: MSDW Web API created to access the 'development' DBMS server.
[2023-05-22 13:03:10,173] INFO in __init__: MSDW Web API created with an authorization file in 'msdw_api_domains_n_keys.csv'
 * Serving Flask app 'web_apis'
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
[2023-05-22 13:03:10,376] INFO in __init__: MSDW Web API created to access the 'development' DBMS server.
[2023-05-22 13:03:10,376] INFO in __init__: MSDW Web API created with an authorization file in 'msdw_api_domains_n_keys.csv'
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 859-188-876
[2023-05-22 13:03:26,395] INFO in auth: request_loader: email: None
[2023-05-22 13:03:26,395] INFO in auth: Users:
127.0.0.1 - - [22/May/2023 13:03:26] "GET /auth/logout HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

`gunicorn`:

```
(.venv) api_svc_account@msdw-api-dev:[api_svc_account/msdw_web_api]$ gunicorn --bind msdw-api-dev.mssm.edu --workers 4 'web_apis:create_app()' --access-logfile - --log-file - --log-level 'info' 
[2023-05-22 13:07:50 -0400] [12229] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2023-05-22 13:07:50 -0400] [12229] [INFO] Listening at: http://10.95.46.212:8000 (12229)
[2023-05-22 13:07:50 -0400] [12229] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-05-22 13:07:50 -0400] [12230] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12230
[2023-05-22 13:07:50 -0400] [12231] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12231
[2023-05-22 13:07:50 -0400] [12232] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12232
[2023-05-22 13:07:50 -0400] [12233] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12233
10.254.166.110 - - [22/May/2023:13:07:58 -0400] "GET /auth/logout HTTP/1.1" 200 10 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
[2023-05-22 13:08:29 -0400] [12229] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:12232)
[2023-05-22 13:08:29 -0400] [12232] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 12232)
[2023-05-22 13:08:29 -0400] [12265] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12265
```

Comment: could you explain please what mean `how is this fixed`?  what is the expected behavior?